# sql two order by give different result

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this sql query below that has 2 order by my dates are

*02/01/2016 - 03/01/2017*

*02/03/2011 - 07/07/2016*

*12/22/2010 - 07/07/2016*

*02/01/2016 - 02/01/2016*

*12/22/2010 - 07/07/2013*

This is the result when i use the query below. But the problem is it is not in order in what i expect for. I want to order first the DateEnd in desc order and then the DateStarted.

```
        Select  top 5  
     Case When dbo.VoluntaryWork.Organization + ' - ' + dbo.VoluntaryWork.OrganizationAddress = ' - ' 
          Then 'N/A' 
          Else dbo.VoluntaryWork.Organization + ' - ' + dbo.VoluntaryWork.OrganizationAddress end AS OrgAddress, 
     Case When isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateStarted, 101),'') = '' or isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateStarted, 101),'') = '01/01/1900' then 'N/A' else isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateStarted, 101),'') end AS DateStarted, 
     Case When isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, 101),'') = '' or isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, 101),'') = '01/01/1900' then 'N/A' else isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, 101),'') end AS DateEnded
          From  dbo.PersonVoluntaryWork 
    Inner Join dbo.VoluntaryWork ON dbo.PersonVoluntaryWork.VoluntaryWorksId = dbo.VoluntaryWork.VoluntaryWorksId
         Where  (dbo.PersonVoluntaryWork.PersonId = @PersonId)
      Order By dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded desc ,dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateStarted desc
```

Comment: That result _IS_ ordered like you want... Unless I'm not seeing something.

Comment: I agree with @ZLK DateEnd is in desc and then DateStarted is desc, from looking at your output on row 2 and 3 you can see.

Comment: @ZLK OMGGG!.... I think I am blind.. I just looking at `02/03/2011 and 02/01/2016` and not looking to its year. Thanks Man.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use another select clause from outside your main query and then apply order by clause like this.. I hope this will work.

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT  top 5  case when dbo.VoluntaryWork.Organization + ' - ' + dbo.VoluntaryWork.OrganizationAddress = ' - ' then 'N/A' 
    else dbo.VoluntaryWork.Organization + ' - ' + dbo.VoluntaryWork.OrganizationAddress end AS OrgAddress, 
    case when isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateStarted, 101),'') = '' or isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateStarted, 101),'') = '01/01/1900' then 'N/A' else isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateStarted, 101),'') end AS DateStarted, 
    case when isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, 101),'') = '' or isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, 101),'') = '01/01/1900' then 'N/A' else isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, 101),'') end AS DateEnded, 
    FROM         dbo.PersonVoluntaryWork INNER JOIN
                      dbo.VoluntaryWork ON dbo.PersonVoluntaryWork.VoluntaryWorksId = dbo.VoluntaryWork.VoluntaryWorksId
WHERE     (dbo.PersonVoluntaryWork.PersonId = @PersonId)
    ORDER BY dbo.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded DESC
    ) A ORDER BY A.DateStarted
```